# 502 Bad Gateway nginx Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, laravel, nginx, bad-gateway

I've made an webapplication, and a page called window only screen that automatically refreshes every 30 seconds. with `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">`

But after a few moments i see 502 Bad Gateway nginx, after refreshing some times. And when I refresh it by myself the page returns normal

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: No, only composer

Answer (score 1):

Also try this method

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload();
      }, 30000); // 30 sec
  });
</script>
```